# How to remedy Imgur "403 Forbidden" errors?

Tags: imgur

Every other image I see hotlinked from Imgur returns a "403 - Forbidden" error.

If I copy and paste the link into my browser the image will load. Or if I delete the initial `i.` in the URL, the image loads.

The image will not load if it's used in a BBCode style tag, or if I right click on it and choose open in a new tab.

Do you know the cause or a fix?

These are a couple of examples that you'll probably be able to see, but I can't unless I do one of those above mentioned actions:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdDHk.png

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0oyt.jpg

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that if you click on either of the image links you have posted you get a 403 forbidden error? What browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, but after copying and pasting the link they'll load. I'm using Chrome 18.0.1025.162 m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that imgur has an outright ban on the site for some reason. No one knows why.

The workaround is to use the site's https connection, then the images will load. We guess imgur didn't ban https://site.com.

Comment: According to imgur's TOS (http://imgur.com/tos), if someone else hotlinked pictures that violate TOS on this site before, imgur will ban not just the pictures, but also the site itself in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat with Greenshot's Imgur Plugin. Greenshot is awesome.

According to Imgur Documentation

> ## Status Code: 403
>
> Forbidden. You don't have access to this action. If you're getting this error, check that you haven't run out of API credits or make sure you're sending the OAuth headers correctly and have valid tokens/secrets.

I assume in my case that many other people love Greenshot and the application just ran out of API credits or something? In your case it sounds like a broken authentication token though I'm knowledge about enough to know how to hypothetically even approach fixing it.

**Edit:**

ShareX a similar screen shot program seems to have run into [a similar problem](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/issues/1138) at some point and the problem on their end was users had to reauthenticate. I'm going to try it on my end and if that works that it might be linked to the problem of hotlink 403 errors.

I wasn't able to relogin to Imgur but fiddling with the configuration settings (or waiting just 20 more minutes while I tried to figure out how to logout) seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Possibly **imgur** does not allow hotlinking, although I couldn't find any mention about that in their Terms Of Service. 
If it does however ban hotlinking, you wouldn't be able to see picture in another website. 
Some services (e.g. Blogger) also did similar thing in the past.

Comment: I'm almost positive they allow hotlinking. Actually pictures become popular on the site, and users earn reputation, based upon the number of times an image is served.

Comment: They allow hotlinking for forums, not for web site UI, galleries, etc.